# Implementing a TCP/IP Connection in a single WPF application C#

Tags: c#, wpf, tcpclient

for a real-time quiz application I'm developing as a personal project for school, I've been trying to incorporate TCP/IP into my single WPF application (i.e not using two separate applications for Client and Server). I've been using TCP Client and Listener classes only as the method I'd like to use (meaning I do not want to use SignalR, sockets or any other packages). However, I've been having some difficulty trying to successfully make this work.

From console, I understand you'd use reader.writeline() etc, but how would I do this in WPF?

This is what I've already done (Eventually I would need to use multithreading as well)

Main Window.XAMl.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        Server Server = new Server();

        Client Client = new Client();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Client Class:

```
public class Client
    {
        public static void Maain(string message) 
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 8080);

            StreamReader ClientInput = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());

            StreamWriter ServerOutput = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());

            Console.WriteLine();

            ServerOutput.WriteLine(message);

            ServerOutput.Flush();

            string server_string = ClientInput.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine(server_string); 

        }
    }
```

Server Class:

```
public class Server
    {
        public static void Maaein() 
        {
            TcpListener server =  new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8080);
            // server has started - message
            server.Start();

            while (true) 
            {

                // accepts tcp client - message
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

                // gets messages from the client
                StreamReader clientInput = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());

                //sends messages from server
                StreamWriter serverOutput = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());

                string message = "";

                Console.WriteLine("Message from Client recieved: " + message);
                Console.WriteLine("Message recieved to Server: " + message);
            
                clientInput.Close();

                serverOutput.Close();

                client.Close();
            
            }
        }        
    }
```

I'm not sure if this works and how to get the classes to talk to each other.

Comment: Instead of posting images of your code, please paste the least reproducible code into your question so we can actually test and give the most accurate question possible :)

Comment: Oh sorry, I've updated it now.

Comment: Do you have any reason why you do not want to use existing libraries/protocols? If you are learning, I would really recommend using a library. Otherwise you are likely to spend quite a bit of time trying to not shoot yourself in the foot. I found MQTT + Json to be fairly easy to get started with, but there are plenty of alternatives.

Comment: It's actually for a personal project relating to school, and they've specifically asked me not to use any other library (other than tcp/ip of course), mainly because they want to see me do all the work myself and not have a library do it for me if that makes sense.  I think you're right though, I might have to look at other libraries because I don't really want to overcomplicate things especially since I've haven't got long until its due. I was also contemplating using SuperSimpleTcp, despite what they've said, but I don't know if it supports multithreading.

Comment: Actually, I might consider using SignalR instead

Comment: By asking you to use raw TCP/IP they effectively ask you to write a multi threaded application. Unless you're studying Computer Science or Electrical Engineering you should not go there.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least a few issues:

```
Server Server = new Server();

Client Client = new Client();
```

This creates a new server and a new client, but if you look at the classes they just contain a static `Maain` method that is never called. So your example will do nothing. So you should either move the implementation to the constructor of the classes, or call the static method instead.

The second problem you will likely encounter is that the server calls `server.AcceptTcpClient()`. This is a "blocking" call, meaning that the single UI thread you are using will be waiting for connections, unable to do anything else, including creating a client. The fix for this is to either use `AcceptTcpClientAsync`, or a background thread. But the first one will require learning about asynchronous programming, and that is a somewhat complex topic. The second requires learning about threads and thread safety, and that is even more complex.

I would start of by writing two separate console based programs, one for the server and one for the client. And I would follow [the guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/sockets/tcp-classes) on how to use these to establish connections. That should let you at least confirm that you are able to send data.

But to get a usable system you will need to consider many other things.

- TCP is a stream based protocol. To send *messages* you need some type of [message framing](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html)
- Do you intend to have a server or peer-to-peer communication?
- How will you handle [dropped connections](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html)?
- And many other things to consider.

If this is schoolwork I would have expected all of this to be mentioned in the teaching material before giving you a task to use TCP directly.

So for any application intended for real use I would highly recommend using existing protocols. This should also be more useful knowledge for anything except demonstrating basic knowledge about tcp/ip. Some popular protocols include http, MQTT, rabbitMQ and gRPC. Some are mainly for client to server communication, while others are better for client-client communication. My impression of SignalR is that it is more intended for webpages than desktop apps, but I have never used it, so I cannot really say anything.